# Can we get a breakdown of the Snowpipe costs?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We know we can use table function <PIPE_USAGE_HISTORY> to get the <CREDITS_USED> however this seems like overall number. We understand, there is also the charge for event notifications or listings:

> In addition to resource consumption, an overhead is included in the utilization costs charged for Snowpipe: 0.06 credits per 1000 files notified or listed via event notifications or REST API calls. This overhead is charged regardless if the event notifications or REST API calls resulted in data loaded.

Is this overhead included in <PIPE_USAGE_HISTORY> <CREDITS_USED> ?

Comment: It is an overall number and the event notification charges are included in it.  Are you looking for that to be broken out or were you looking for a more detailed cost at a file level?

Comment: @MikeWalton both if possible but either would be nice.

Comment: I don't think you'll get the breakout of the per file costs from Snowflake, since the price is "included".  You could figure that out by just doing a file count, though.  As for the per-file snowpipe costs, I'd recommend making a request for that from Snowflake.  You could "estimate" that cost by using the bytes loaded, though.